# Convert uppercase string to lowercase string in JS manually

Tags: javascript, char, uppercase, lowercase

Trying to write a function which returns the calling string value converted to
lowercase. The trick is I can't use [`toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase).

Below is what I have so far.

```
function charChange(char){
    for (var i=0; i<char.length; i++){
        var char2=charCodeAt(char[i])+32;
        var char3=String.fromCharCode(char2);
        if (char3 !== charCodeAt(97-122){
            alert("Please enter only letters in the function")
        }
    }
    return char;
}
```

Comment: you're missing a closing parenthesis line 5

Comment: Why can you not use `.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `char` is a reserved word in JS that you are not allowed to use. If `char` is an array (which it looks like), it should be `chars`.

Comment: @Redu, maybe homework..

Comment: Also `charCodeAt(97-122)` becomes `charCodeAt(-25)`, which makes no sense because `String.prototype.charCodeAt()` (1) must be called on a string and (2) takes an index, not a code point.

Comment: more importantly I believe `charCodeAt` is a method, not a function! You might want to do `char[i].charCodeAt(0)` instead of `charCodeAt(char[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the uppercase letters of a string to lowercase **manually** (if you're not doing it manually, you should just use [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)), you must:

1. Write the boilerplate function stuff:

   ```
   function strLowerCase(str) {
       let newStr = "";
       // TODO
       return newStr;
   }
   ```
2. Loop over each character of the original string, and get its code point:

   ```
   function strLowerCase(str) {
       let newStr = "";
       for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
           let code = str.charCodeAt(i);
           // TODO
       } return newStr;
   }
   ```
3. Check if the character is an uppercase letter. [In ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif), characters with code points between `65` and `90` (inclusive) are uppercase letters.

   ```
   function strLowerCase(str) {
       let newStr = "";
       for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
           let code = str.charCodeAt(i);
           if(code >= 65 && code <= 90) {
               // TODO
           } // TODO
       } return newStr;
   }
   ```
4. If the character is uppercase, add 32 to its code point to make it lowercase (yes, this was a deliberate design decision by the creators of ASCII). Regardless, append the new character to the new string.

   ```
   function strLowerCase(str) {
       let newStr = "";
       for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
           let code = str.charCodeAt(i);
           if(code >= 65 && code <= 90) {
               code += 32;
           } newStr += String.fromCharCode(code);
       } return newStr;
   }
   ```
5. Test your new function:

   ```
   strLowerCase("AAAAAAABBBBBBBCCCCCZZZZZZZZZaaaaaaaaaaa&$*(@&(*&*#@!");
   // "aaaaaaabbbbbbbccccczzzzzzzzzaaaaaaaaaaa&$*(@&(*&*#@!"
   ```

Comment: very nice explanation

Comment: Thank you for explaining step by step, this really helped me understand a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

[`charCodeAt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charCodeAt.asp) is a method called on a String, it's not a function. So you apply the method on a string and give the position of the character you want to convert as the parameter. Also as [MultiplyByZer0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2688027/multiplybyzer0) mentioned the word `char` is reserved: look at the [list of reserved words](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp).

The following code fixes the problem:

```js
function charChange(str) {
  var result = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    var code = str[i].charCodeAt(0);
    
    if(code >= 65 && code <= 90) {
    
      var letter = String.fromCharCode(code+32);
    
      result += letter // append the modified character

    
    } else {

      result += str[i]  // append the original character
      
    }
    
  }

   return result;
}

console.log(charChange('j#aMIE'));
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the two most elegant solutions I can think of (at the moment). See comments within the code and don't hesitate to ask if anything is unclear.

```js
function charChange1 (str) {
  let result = '';
  const len = str.length;
  
  // go over each char in input string...
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const c = str[i];
    const charCode = c.charCodeAt(0);

    if (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) {
      // if it is not a uppercase letter,
      // just append it to the output
      // (also catches special characters and numbers)
      result += c;
    } else {
      // else, transform to lowercase first
      result += String.fromCharCode(charCode - 65 + 97);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function charChange2 (str) {
    // Array.prototype.slice.call(str) converts
    // an array-like (the string) into an actual array
    // then, map each entry using the same logic as above
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(str)
      .map(function (c) {
        const charCode = c.charCodeAt(0);

        if (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) return c;

        return String.fromCharCode(charCode - 65 + 97);
      })
      // finally, join the array to a string
      .join('');
}

console.log(charChange1("AAAAsfasSGSGSGSG'jlj89345"));
console.log(charChange2("AAAAsfasSGSGSGSG'jlj89345"));
```

---

(On a side node, it would of course be possible to replace the magic numbers by constants declared as calls to `'A'.charCodeAt(0)`)

(A second side node: Don't use *char* since it is a reserved word in JavaScript; I prefer *c*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to convert the string to lower case:

```
:%s/.*/\L&/
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const lowerCase = ()=>{

    let welcome = prompt("Enter your string");
let lower = '';
for(let i=0; i<welcome.length;i++){
    code =  welcome.charCodeAt(i);

   if(code >= 65 && code <= 90){
    let co = code+32;
    console.log(co);
    lower += String.fromCharCode(co);
   }
   else
   {
    lower +=String.fromCharCode(code) ;
   }
   console.log(lower);
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).